# pdf in request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, post

so for an application i have to send a pdf into an api then do some stuff with the pdf and then send it to another api and then return the result

problem n1:

i dont know how to get access to the pdf i sent with Postman 
i tried

```
$file = $request->get('upload_file');
```

which doesnt seem to work since i cant get the file which is called

```
test.pdf
```

and has a content of

```
Test
Dit is een test
```

so in the meantime i do

```
$parser = new Parser();
$pdf = $parser->parseFile('pdf/test.pdf');
$text = pdf->getText();
```

problem n2:

the api i sent the transformed pdf to claims the requestbody is invalid
 i use Guzzle for the request

```
    $headers =
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json']
        ];
    $body =
        '{
            "documents": [
            {
            "language": "nl",
            "id": "1",
            "text":"' . $text . '"}
            ]
        }';

    $client = new Client();

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/KeyPhrases', $headers, $body);
```

it gives

```
`Client error: `POST
```

https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/KeyPhrases
     `resulted in a`400 Bad Request`response:\n
     {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid request","innerError": 
     {"code":"InvalidRequestBodyFormat","message":"Request body 
     (truncated...)\n`
    //cant seem to format this correctly

so can anyone plz help me? 
and explain what i am doing wrong if they have the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your question (n1), you can get the uploaded file using:

```
$file = $request->file('test'); // where 'test' is the 'name' of this file input
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

For the second part (n2), it looks like you are passing an invalid body. Try this:

```
$body = [
    'documents' => [
        [
            'language' => 'nl',
            'id' => '1',
            'text' => $text,
        ],
    ]
];
$headers = [
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json' // this might not be needed since Guzzle should add this automatically
];
$client->request('POST','https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/KeyPhrases', [
    'json' => $body,
    'headers' => $headers,
    'debug' => true, // to get more info on the error ...
]);
```

Comment: i tried it but now it says the subscription key is incorrect but it works if i do it directly wiht postman which is straight up confusing

Comment: You could try enabling the `debug` option to see if that gives you more info. See my updated answer.

Comment: k nvm had to thow it together into 1 big request thx for the solution